# A/C clutch 2000 grand marquis is leaking

Tags: ac, pontiac, leak, grand-marquis

So I just changed my blend door actuator because my car would continuously blow really hot air and my boss said that could be the problem. After I changed it, put everything back together I added one can of a/c pro because I had no Freon in it at all. After I added the Freon it was still just hot air. So I cut my car off and started looking around and seen that the front of the clutch was leaking gas not oil.

If anyone can help me that would be great.

p.s.  The air conditioning hasn't ran in a good while. At least 6+ months.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

From your description, its the front seal of the Air Conditioning (AC) compressor that is leaking.  And its not really clear on what causes that to leak, except excess shaft / internal bearing wear.  With that said, you could evacuate the system, pull the compressor, remove the A/C clutch, remove the seal and re-install a new one, but my guess it would be much less hassle (and likely cost) to just replace the entire A/C compressor.

The A/C clutch has nothing to do with sealing refrigerant at all.  It only controls the ability to spin the compressor shaft or not, via a simple electro-magnetic pressure plate clutch.

And as for the temperature blend door inside the passenger compartment, a simple test to verify it is shut is to measure the temperature of vent air (A/C off) at full cool setting, while car is moving, and after the car is warmed up for a few minutes.  Generally you would see a temperature of 5 to 7 degrees F over outside temperature, depending on your vehicle speed.  The extra heat comes from the engine compartment heating things up a bit. Best tool for that job is one of these:

[image: glass thermometer]

That tool is also handy for solving arguments about thermostat settings in the house.  Pays for itself in days!